# Sort array using PHP - group by key value

Tags: php

I grab data by running a cURL operation and then use:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    print_r($data)
?>
```

to output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 258378365
            [firstName] => Test
            [lastName] => McTest
            [phone] => 1235550101
            [email] => test.mctest@example.com
            [date] => January 10, 2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 253994842
            [firstName] => Jane
            [lastName] => McTest
            [phone] => 1235550101
            [email] => jane.mctest@example.com
            [date] => December 13, 2018
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 253994843
            [firstName] => Jane
            [lastName] => McTest
            [phone] => 1235550101
            [email] => jane.mctest@example.com
            [date] => January 10, 2019
        )

)
```

Is it possible to **group my results by date**?

I can display my results like this:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $entry){
    echo $entry['id'];
}
?>
```

However, I'd like to group my results by `$entry['date']`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to sort them client side (javascript) or server side (php). That's slightly different...

Comment: @quirimmo Apologies. I'd like to sort with PHP. Will amend question.

Comment: so remove the javascript tag. That's out of scope

Comment: So did you review the PHP manual pages on all the types of SORT that are available?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't. Will check just now.

Comment: That should really be your first post of call, and only when you have completely exhausted those options or your attempt to implement one should you ask here for help, otherwise it looks like a DIFM

Comment: Get a look to uasort [Here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uasort.php). Maybe its response to what you want to do

Comment: @KubiRoazhon Brilliant - thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) > strtotime($b['date']);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.

Answer (score 0):

The following will sort the array by date in ascending order.

```
usort($data, function ($x,$y) {
    return strtotime($x['date']) - strtotime($y['date']);
});
```

_Edit: I may have misunderstood the question so if the intent is to retrieve only the dates in a separate array then perform the following:

```php
$dates = array_column($data, 'date');
```

If you needed the dates sorted after this then perform the `usort` example above by passing the `$dates` array as follows:

```php
usort($dates, function ($x,$y) {
    return strtotime($x) - strtotime($y);
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: How does sorting an array group it by any key?

Comment: @common-sense I have added an explanation and alternative in case I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @nico-haase I have added an alternative which assigns only the dates to a new Array. I may have misunderstood what the op meant by 'group' so I have offered another option.